# How to get current page title inside a page's template

Tags: title

I am trying to get the page title to show up inside various h1, h2 and p tags that i have part of the page template - so that when the template is applied to a page it will make the current page's page title appear wherever I add a shortcode or whatever is needed to pull the page title. When I add the following i am getting a blank...

Here's what I mean: I want "Find the best " to basically pull the page title so that if the title is video games it will display as "Find the best video games"

```
<h1 class="btx-heading-text btx-secondary-font btx-s-text-color btx-s- 
text-border" style="padding-right:25%; padding-bottom:5%; letter- 
spacing:-2px;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Find the best&nbsp; 
</span><span style="color: rgb(126, 131, 142);"><?php get_the_title() ? 
></span></h1>
```

Currently, I only get the following "Find the best"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_the_title()` does not output anything - it's meant for being saved to a variable. Use just `the_title();` in its place - that way it will be output. :)

Comment: When i add the <?php the_title(); ?> in a page itself it comes out blank. However when i added the <?php the_title(); ?> to a page template file it worked so if i wanted to add <?php the_title(); ?> to a single page itself how would i do so? Also to provide more context i want to add the <?php the_title(); ?> inside a shortcode in order to have the shortcode replace part of it with the specific page's title, how would i do that? 

For Example: 
the shortcode [products columns="3" attribute="season" terms="warm" orderby="date"]

Except replace the seasons with the page title... thanks!

Comment: Right, you can't add PHP directly into the editor. If you want to add it manually every time rather than embedding it into a template, that's deserving of a separate question.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/314457/how-to-get-current-page-title-inside-a-page-itself-in-a-shortcode-and-in-page-co

I have created a new question - hope you are able to help, thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ...

```
<?php echo get_the_title() ? 
></span></h1>
```