# How to get current page title inside a page itself in a shortcode and in page content

Tags: shortcode, title

When i add the

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

to a page template file it works and is able to pull the page title inside html tags however if i wanted to add

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

to a single page itself how would i do so?

Also to provide more context; i want to add the

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

inside a shortcode in order to have the shortcode replace part of it with the specific page's title, how would i do that?

For Example: the shortcode [products columns="3" attribute="season" terms="warm" orderby="date"] Except replace the seasons with the page title... thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can create a shortcode to fetch the title of current page. Try copying the following snippet in your child theme's functions.php

```
function post_title_shortcode(){
    return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode('post_title','post_title_shortcode');
```

Use `[post_title]` shortcode to display the title of the post or page.

Comment: `global $post;` and `$post->ID` are redundant.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: So now that the function is just returning `get_the_title()`, you might as well just use `add_shortcode('post_title','get_the_title');`

Comment: This works on displaying the page title inside the page but it doesn't work at adding it inside the shortcode so for example: 

[product_category category="[post_title]" columns="3" per_page="5"]
it results in just showing the following " columns="4" per_page="5"]

Where the normal shortcode is 
[product_category category="men" columns="3" per_page="14"]

Comment: You can't use shortcodes inside shortcodes like that. You should really find an alternative way to do what you want.